# How could add custom markup to form field in joomla module xml

Tags: php, xml, joomla, module, joomla3.0

I want to add custom markup to an form field in joomla xml. I want to add `<i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>` in this radio button.

This code doesn't work, so the `fa` icon does not show.

```
<field name="face_book_icon" type="radio" default="" label="Face Book Icon" description="Face Book Icon" >
        <option value="facebook-official"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> icon 1</option>
        <option value="facebook">icon 2</option>
        <option value="facebook-square">icon 3</option>
</field>
```

- i already import fontawesome libraries.

sample idea of what i want.
[image: sample idea]

when i try the with your ( @jonasfh ) answer the FA icon will come. but it's on one raw,one radio button

```
<field name="face_book_icon" type="radio" default="" label="Face Book Icon" description="Face Book Icon" >
        <option value="facebook-official" class="fa fa-facebook-official " > icon 1</option>
        <option value="facebook" class="fa fa-facebook"> icon 2</option>
        <option value="facebook-square" class="fa fa-facebook-square" >icon 3</option>
    </field>
```

Here the screenshot - [image]

Comment: This is an incomplete question. Are you creating your own module, modifying a core module or any thing else? Give details of which files your are going to modify etc? Also add the code of your default.php file or tmpl file.

Comment: @AmitRay yes sir, i'm developing my own module. I want to show in backend side (administrator side) show icons in option field.. (i'll attach the sample idea of mine under the post.. ) that's what i want in xml file form field.

Comment: Could you post the html output for the checkboxes also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To modify the markup for the field, you need to override the current output of the radio button field. This is possible by copying the file

`layouts/joomla/form/field/radio.php`

to your template, in the folder:

`/templates/yourtemplate/html/layouts/joomla/form/field/radio.php`

where yourtemplate is the folder where your current template lives. Now you can modify the radio.php - file, adding `<i>` - tags. You can try adding the tags inside the label-tags (on line 83), but how it is displayed will depend on how the template renders radio buttons. Alternatively try adding the tags on line 81. You also need to handle different icons for the different options. This might be handled by adding different classes to the options directly in the xml-file?

`<label for="<?php echo $oid; ?>">
    <i <?php echo $optionClass; ?>></i><?php echo $option->text; ?>
</label>`

More on output overrides can be found [here](https://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides).

One more thing: It might be possible to achieve what you want by simply adding the correct classes to the options in the xml:

`<field name="face_book_icon" type="radio" default="" label="Face Book Icon" description="Face Book Icon" >
  <option value="facebook-official" class="fa fa-facebook">icon 1</option>
  <option value="facebook">icon 2</option>
  <option value="facebook-square">icon 3</option>
</field>`

Depending on how the css is setup, it might work straight out of the box, or with small modifications to the css.

Comment: Thank you for reply my question. i have no idea where put the `<i></i>` code. can you help me.

Comment: If i have more radio button and it's has different icon. how could i add? ( I'm beginner to joomla, sorry for interrupting ) :(

Comment: Try to add the classes to the options like I described above. I will modify the example code so it should work.

Comment: anyone there to help me plz. see the post end to my latest problem.